# How is the transition of code made in view source page

Tags: html, xhtml

While viewing a page source in fireBug the code is displayed in html. But my code is written in xhtml. How is the conversions made.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Firebug does not show the source. It shows a representation of the live DOM.

Additionally, browsers will treat XHTML as HTML if the server tells them it is `Content-Type: text/html` instead of `Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml`.

Comment: "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" is this the name space which converts our code to html

Comment: That isn't a namespace (the namespace is specified in the `xmlns` attribute) and, as I implied, the Doctype (and the namespace) don't trigger XML mode, the Content-Type HTTP header does.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug dose not show the source code .Firebug use as a debugging tool .Main Reason of use firebug

```
-->The Key to Successful Web Development
-->Debugging and Testing the Web with Firebug
-->Debug and tune applications on the fly with Firebug
-->Quick & Easy CSS Development with Firebug So on
```

when we try to see source view of a page browser return the code as a plain Html.This is one of reason you cannot see your code which is written in xhtml